# RestKit 0.20 Mapping problems

Tags: objective-c, xcode, http, core-data, restkit

I'm getting the following error when i'm making a request and trying to put the response in Core Data.

```
Performing managed object mapping with a nil managed object cache:
Unable to update existing object instances by identification attributes. Duplicate objects     may be created.
```

I set the identifactionAttributes and i'm using Object Manager to configure the request operation. And i still receive "Unable to update existing object instances ... "

```
objectMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Entity"     inManagedObjectStore:self.managedObjectStore];
            objectMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"route_id" ];
            [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
             @"point_alt" : @"point_alt",
             @"point_lat" : @"point_lat",
             @"point_long" : @"point_long",
             @"location_id" : @"location_id",
             @"route_id" : @"route_id"
             }];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] requestWithObject:nil      method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:path parameters:paramsWithEncr];

RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:request   managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
        NSLog(@"Loading mapping result: %d", result.count);
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Fail!");
    }];
```

Comment: That message you're getting is just a warning. Do you just want to get rid of the warning? Or do you have some bigger problems? Like no objects are stored in the database at all?

Comment: No objects are stored in the database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't configure the Core Data integration with the Object Manager. This is what you should do if you have the same problem:

```
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
NSString *path = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Store.sqlite"];
[managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:path fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:nil];
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];
```